# match all characters minus trailing whitespace then characters between curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a string like such `parameter parameter2 {characters}` where there can be any number of parameters and any number of spaces between the parameters and then an additional variable number of spaces after the list of parameters and then characters between curly braces. 
 My attempt `/(?:([^{]*)\s*)?(\{.*\})?/`.

I need capture group 1 to be parameter parameter2 and `capture group 2` to be `{characters}`


**background**
I have a publish/subscribe pattern setup and the "thing" to publish and subscribe to is not controlled by me and could contain any number of spaces, the curly braces and what's inside of them is parsed as json and passed as a parameter to the subscribing method.

Comment: `'parameter parameter2 {characters}'.match(/(?:([^{]*)\s*)?(\{.*\})?/).slice(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([^{]*?)\s*(\{.*\})
```

Simply use this and grab group 1 and group 2.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/13

```
var re = /([^{]*?)\s*(\{.*\})/gm;
var str = 'parameter parameter2 {characters}\n\n\n';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex, you have seems to be working fine, but you need to slice the resultant array to get the response you want like

```
var myarray = 'parameter parameter2 {characters}'.match(/(?:([^{]*)\s*)?(\{.*\})?/).slice(1)
```

If you are looking for an exact array without using a slice/splice, you can try split like

```
'parameter parameter2 {characters}'.split(/\s+(?={)/)
```

Comment: trailing white spaces aren't removed for me if there are multiple.

Comment: so `var myarray = 'parameter parameter2   _______ {characters}'.match(/(?:([^{]*)\s*)?(\{.*\})?/)`

Comment: the _ is a space in this context.

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty try `'parameter parameter2   {characters}'.match(/(.*?)\s+(\{.*)/).slice(1)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`([\w+\s*]*)(\{\w+)\})`